# Why is scanner skipping the if else statement

Tags: java, if-statement

Pretty straightforward code, if I change string K to "Bye" I receive an error, only the if else structure works, not the if else if else. Please help me understand why.

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String k = "Hi";
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(k);
    if (scnr.next().equals("Hi")){
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }
    else if (scnr.next().equals("Bye")){
    System.out.println("No");
    }
    else {
    System.out.println("Maybe");
    }
}
```

Comment: Because each call to next() reads the **next** token. Not the one that have been read by the previous call to next().

Answer (score 2):

You should save the "next" result in a variable because every time you call next you try to get the next element. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next()). You can check, if there is a next with hasNext. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext())

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String k = "Hi";
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(k);
    String read = scnr.next();
    if (read.equals("Hi")){
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }
    else if (read.equals("Bye")){
    System.out.println("No");
    }
    else {
    System.out.println("Maybe");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Each time you use `next()` you continue iterating, in your case no item to further iterate exists, so do something like:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String k = "Bye";
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(k);
    String element = scnr.next();

    if (element.equals("Hi")){
        System.out.println("Yes");
    } else if (element.equals("Bye")){
        System.out.println("No");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Maybe");
    }
}
```

In your case if you're not looping over, you only have 1 time to call `next()`.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you call next() method from Scanner instance, it moves (in other words, it gives you the element and move on.

In the particular example, here is what happened:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String k = "Bye";
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(k); // scnr is at the start of string k
    if (scnr.next().equals("Hi")){ // scnr gives you "Bye" here; 
                                   // you compare it with constant "Hi" and 
                                   // throw away that variable;
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }
    else if (scnr.next().equals("Bye")){ // here scnr is at the end of string k
                                         // therefore, it can't give you next element
        System.out.println("No");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Maybe");
    }
}
```

The followings is how you correct this:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
    String k = "Hi";
    Scanner scnr = new Scanner(k);
    String myNextElement = scnr.next();
    if (myNextElement.equals("Hi")){
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }
    else if (myNextElement.equals("Bye")){
        System.out.println("No");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Maybe");
    }
}
```